# Run multiple cypress suites on docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, cypress

I am trying to run cypress suites on docker compose but out of two only one runs, is there a way to fulfill multiple runs?

Here is the compose file:

```html
version: '3.2'
services:
  suite1:
    container_name: suite1
    image: 'cyp1'
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_environment=test
    working_dir: /test
    network_mode: 'host'
    volumes:
      - ./:/test
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    command: '--browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/wfo/speech-iq/configuration/**'
  suite2:
    container_name: suite2
    image: 'cyp2'
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_environment=test
    working_dir: /test1
    network_mode: 'host'
    volumes:
      - ./:/test1
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    command: '--browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/siq/speech-iq/configuration/**'
```

Error:

```
suite2    | Xvfb exited with a non zero exit code.
suite2    | 
suite2    | There was a problem spawning Xvfb.
suite2    | 
suite2    | This is likely a problem with your system, permissions, or installation of Xvfb.
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: what is the docker compose command you run ?

Comment: docker-compose up

Comment: i don't understand, it should work out of the box, to debug, you should try to run `docker-compose up suite1` to see what it logs